# drag and Drop reordering the table items

Tags: reactjs

My query is when I drag an item and drop it to any position the items in the table should be auto arrange i.e when I try to drag item with index 0 to item with index 2 the 2 should be adjust at no 3 with index 3 and 3 at 4 so on so fourth. can any one help me in this scenario help will be appreciated .... plzzz explain in demo so it can easily undersatnd

****Note : question is in React js please help is needed in react also****

Comment: It would be great if you provide your source code too.

Comment: that is not possible because that code is from project..

Comment: Use react-dnd (https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/overview)

Comment: @VijayaraghavanSundararaman i have already implemented that... but the problem its just switch the index's not shift

Comment: Got It, please check this example from react-dnd. https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_hooks_js/04-sortable/simple?from-embed=&file=/src/Container.jsx:971-1287